# H4n panning issue in pro tools

Tags: pro-tools, field, zoom-h4n, panning

i did a days worth of field recording a while back into input 1 of my H4n which is the left channel. it played back into my headphones at the time on both sides. however when i play back what i recorded that day on pro tools it only plays back in my left monitor. is there some way to get it centrally panned? thats a whole days stuff gone otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear where your problem is. Do you need help in protools to get the sound in the center image? Or do you want to get a stereo image from 1 channel audio?

Protools answer: drag your files to 2 mono tracks from the stereo track. Delete panning automation on the mono tracks.
Stereo image: Unless you used a stereo mic(setup) the latter is impossible. If you used channel 1 of the line input with a mono mic this is all you have unfortunately.

Cheers,
Arnoud

Comment: Not quite impossible depending uoon one's point of view.  A pseudo-stereo can be achieved by slipping a duplicate out of sync (by a whole lot) and panning it.  Sometimes this can actually be desirable.  Building party scenes for instance, I like using a combo of more narrow XY stereo in conjunction with dry walla or dry F/S tracks in the pseudo-stereo method.

Comment: Hi Stavro, yes ofcourse. I was trying to refer to the fact that if the 2nd channel is not recorded, there is no way that you can retrieve it. Hopes this more clear.